# Как игнорировать ошибочные строки в postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, автоматизация

Прилетела задача по автоматизации выгрузки из postgres.
Использую код типа:

```
copy (select *
  from
      (select * from table) q) 
      TO PROGRAM 'gzip > share/файл.csv.gzip' With CSV DELIMITER ';' HEADER encoding 'WIN';
```

По умолчанию форматирование БД в UTF-8. При тестовых выгрузках сталкивался с ошибкой с перекодированием данных (чаще всего с символом "ë" - албанская ё).
Учитывая, что выгрузка необходима на регулярной основе, не хотелось бы ловить постоянные ошибки на этапе формирования исходных данных. Можно ли как-то игнорировать ошибку? Например, игнорировать строку, в которой ошибка или не перекодировать ее.

Comment: А что мешает вместо тупого `select * from table` выполнять требуемые проверки или преобразования прямо в команде на выгрузку? Если известно, какой символ и в каком поле вызывает проблему - ну так есть `REPLACE()`...

Comment: Определенный символ "чаще всего", но бывают исключения.
Сейчас решил попробовать выгружать без encoding и и переводить в cp1251 питоном. Дописываю скрипт, буду тестить. По результату отпишусь.

Comment: По итогу питон натыкается на ту же проблему, спасибо @Akina, воспользовался твоим решением через replace